# Bash - Get files for last 12 hours / sophisticated name format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I have a set of logs which have the names as follows:

> SystemOut_15.07.20_23.00.00.log 
> SystemOut_15.07.21_10.27.17.log 
>   SystemOut_15.07.21_16.48.29.log 
> SystemOut_15.07.22_15.57.46.log 
>   SystemOut_15.07.22_13.03.46.log

From that list I need to get only files for last 12 hours.
So as an output I will receive:

> SystemOut_15.07.22_15.57.46.log
>  SystemOut_15.07.22_13.03.46.log

I had similar issue with files having below names but was able to resolve that quickly as the date comes in an easy format:

> servicemix.log.2015-07-21-11 
> servicemix.log.2015-07-22-12
>   servicemix.log.2015-07-22-13

So I created a variable called 'day':

```
day=$(date -d '-12 hour' +%F-%H)
```

And used below command to get the files for last 12 hours:

```
ls | awk -F. -v x=$day '$3 >= x'
```

Can you help to have that done with SystemOut files as they have such name syntax containing underscore which confuses me.

Comment: Can't you search for the files by the last modified timestamp using `find` instead of parsing their names?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot as their creation and modify time doesn't make sense in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the date-time in log file's name is in the format
    YY.MM.DD_HH24.MI.SS,

```
day=$(date -d '-12 hour' +%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S.log)
```

Prepend the century to the 2 digit year in the log file name and then compare

```
ls | awk -F_ -v x=$day '"20"$2"_"$3 >= x'
```

Alternatively, as Ed Morton suggested, find can be used like so:

```
find . -type f -name '*.log' -cmin -720
```

This returns the log files created within last 720 minutes. To be precise, this means file status was last changed within the past 720 minutes. -mmin option can be used to search by modification time.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Thank you!